# Is there an elegant way of refering to this scenario?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I simulated cometary activity in three different scenarios: local (confined to a certain region on the nucleus), global (encompassing the entire nucleus), and global except local.

While it is simple to refer to the first two scenarios (e.g., "In the local/global activity model, ..."), it is awkward to refer to the third one (e.g., "In the global except local activity model, ..."), and can even irritate the reader. Is there a more elegant/succinct/better way to refer to this scenario? To get a sense of the scale/relation of these areas, imagine the nucleus were Earth, then the local area would be something like a large country.

The scenario itself is straightforward to understand, but I find it very difficult to find and adjective that is unambiguous in its description. But I also really want to aviod using either numbers or lengthy explanations every time.

Alternatives that I came up with, but that don't convince me either:

1. global without local (activity)
2. global minus local (activity)
3. global but local (activity)
4. anti-local (activity)
5. inverted local (activity)
6. reversed local (activity)
7. negative local (activity)
8. external (activity)
9. surrounding (activity)
10. enclosing (activity)
11. encompassing (activity)
12. global excluding local (activity)

Comment: _non-local_ would usually be seen as meaning the complement.

Comment: **extra-local** would be a locative variant to **non-**: local, extra-local, and global.

Comment: If I'm interpreting this correctly, the nucleus is divided into two regions (let's call them A and B).  The local model covers region A only, the global model covers regions A and B together, and you want a term for the model that only covers region B?  If so, I'd suggest **peripheral**.

Comment: Is there some reason that inner and outer don't work? For instance, we have the solar system, the inner solar system, and the outer solar system.

Comment: It would help if we knew how you were dividing the nucleus.

Comment: @StuartF sorry, good point. So if the nucleus were Earth, e.g., the local area would be something like a large country. That being said though, I already really like some of the suggestions here! Sorry I didn't reply earlier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so to close this, I just answer my own question and tell you how I decided. Thanks everyone again for your suggestions. This was difficult to decide, but ultimately, I chose "non-local", due to its brevity and use of simple language. It still needs a short introduction/explanation, but after that, I think it's intuitive enough to be memorable.